# PHP strict standard error in simple Joomla module?

Tags: php, joomla

I'm doing a tutorial on joomla module, but I'm getting a strict standard error with PHP.

Error:

> Strict standards: Non-static method modReviewsHelper::getReviews()
>   should not be called statically in
>   C:\wamp\www\Joomla_2.5\modules\mod_reviews\mod_reviews.php on line 7
>   Call Stack

mod_reviews.php

```
<?php

defined('_JEXEC')or die('Restricted access here?');

require_once(dirname(__FILE__).DS.'helper.php');

$reviews = modReviewsHelper::getReviews($params);

require(JModuleHelper::getLayoutPath('mod_reviews'));
?>
```

helper.php

```
<?php
class modReviewsHelper{

    function getReviews( $params ){
        return 'I am a happy user!';
    }
}
?>
```

tmpl/default.php

```
<?php
defined('_JEXEC')or die('Restricted access here?');
echo $reviews;
?>
```

How do I fix this and to make sure that this does not happen in the future?

Comment: "Non-static method should not be called statically" means you should mark that method as `static` if you are calling it like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
class modReviewsHelper{

    static function getReviews( $params ){
        return 'I am a happy user!';
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to back end in joomla
1) click administrator -> Global configuration
2) go to **server** tab
3) make error reporting : "NONE" in server setting
:-)